# php code to zip and auto download a file. Works in Windows but not in Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, download, ubuntu-12.04, php-ziparchive

I've got a project about showing all files of root directory in a list and the user can browse through files-directories, search a file by name,with the button downloadAll he can download all files at the current list.To make the downloadAll button work I use downloadAll.php code which by getting the current directory can create a zip file and auto download it. It works fine in windows. I'm trying to run the same project at linux but in that case it downloads an empty zipped file. Also when I try to open it this message appears:

```
Archive:  /tmp/archived_name.zip
[/tmp/archived_name.zip]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /tmp/archived_name.zip or
          /tmp/archived_name.zip.zip, and cannot find /tmp/archived_name.zip.ZIP, period.
```

downloadZip.php:

```
<?php
if ((isset($_GET['currentdirectory'])) && ($_GET['currentdirectory']!="")){
    $the_folder = $_GET['currentdirectory']; 
}
else {
    $the_folder = "/var/www/my_project";
}

    $the_folder1 = $the_folder;

$zip_file_name = 'archived_name.zip';

$download_file= true;

class FlxZipArchive extends ZipArchive {

    public function addDir($location, $name) {
        $this->addEmptyDir(str_replace("./","",$name));

        $this->addDirDo($location, str_replace("./","",$name));
    } 

    private function addDirDo($location, $name) {
        $name .= '/';
        $location .= '/';

        $dir = opendir ($location);
        while ($file = readdir($dir))
        {
            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;

            $do = (filetype( $location . $file) == 'dir') ? 'addDir' : 'addFile';

                $this->$do($location . $file, str_replace("./","",$name) . $file);
        }
    } 
}

$za = new FlxZipArchive;
$res = $za->open($zip_file_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if($res === TRUE) 
{
    $za->addDir($the_folder1, basename($the_folder1));
    $za->close();
}
else  { echo 'Could not create a zip archive';}

if ($download_file)
{
    ob_get_clean();
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private", false);
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($zip_file_name) . ";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_file_name));
    readfile($zip_file_name);
}
unlink("archived_name.zip");
?>
```

Comment: "empty zip file" probably means something different to you than me. Is the file actually empty as in zero bytes? Or is your zip program just not able to see files? I assume there is likely some php error being thrown out in the zip file. I suggest opening the zip file in a text editor and looking for a php error.

Comment: I opened the file with a txt editor and it is empty.

Comment: So then you likely have an error that is happening elsewhere. Try setting `$download_file` to false and set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to see if there are any errors. If that doesn't work, try viewing the web server error logs. For apache they default to `/var/log/apache2/access.log` or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your time firstly. I don't know how to set error_reporting(E_ALL) but in /var/log/apache2/access.log the last line that appeared when i tried to use download all in the first screen that appears(the root directory) is 192.168.1.5 - - [29/Sep/2014:20:32:51 +0300] "GET /my_project/downloadZip.php?currentdirectory= HTTP/1.1" 200 435 "http://192.168.1.5/my_project/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"

Comment: The problem was actually on my_project directory privileges.Thank you for your time :/

Comment: The access log will log every time someone requests a page on your site. I wrote access.log but I made a mistake and it should be `error.log`. If the problem was permissions, the error log would have said something along the lines of `Permission Denied in unknown` which would mean apache didn't have permission to view the file or `Permission Denied in "scriptName.php" on line "line number"...` which would mean the script didn't have permission to read/write a file. You could tell whether it was read or write by what is happening at that line number.

Comment: As i was looking at the access.log i also read error.log and there i realised it had to do with permissions. I would never find that without your anwer. thnx

Comment: I added an answer so you could close the question when you get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have an error that is happening elsewhere. Try setting `$download_file` to false and set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to see if there are any errors. If that doesn't work, try viewing the web server error logs. For apache they default to `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.